# "crime or crimes"? & "are or is"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I've read some essays in order to improve my english but I am confused about the first sentences whetever or not to be right.

"Media should stop these crime like acts."

or

"Media should stop these crime**s** like acts."

---

"The information they give about the renowned people **are** neither useful nor entertaining."

or

"The information they give about the renowned people **is** neither useful nor entertaining.

Which are the right versions?

Comment: The first question should use hyphenation to make the adjectival use clear: *Is it **crlme-like** acts or **crimes-like** acts?*

Comment: _Information_ is a non-count noun, so it takes the singular verb _is_.

Comment: Actually i don't know, maybe the writer forget to use hyphenation or the book has a  printing error. Which one is right?